# Selection of M square numbers to make a square

Tags: problem-solving, square-numbers

I came across a question during an exam of computational mathematics to which I could think of no solution other than a brute force approach.

> Given the squares of first 9 natural numbers, i.e $1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81$ select exactly $m$ squares such that the sum of the squares is a square number as well, if such a selection is possible. The selected squares should be minimum possible values and a square can be selected any number of times from 0 to m.

For example, if $m = 2$, the selected squares can be $9$ and $16$ as well as $36$ and $64$, but the answer will be $9$ and $16$ as it is the smallest possible selection. Similarly, if $m = 3$, a possible selection is $1,4,4$ where $4$ is selected twice.

Could someone please suggest the correct method of attempting such question mathematically, since m can be as large as $10^6$?

Comment: Standard Pythagorean triples would probably be a good place to start. How about $3^2+4^2=5^2$? I suppose I am not sure I understand the problem, though. For example, if $m=4$, then how about $4\cdot 1^2+0\cdot 2^2+0\cdot 3^2+0\cdot 4^2 = 4 = 2^2$?

Comment: I fail to understand how is the sum of $4$ and $16$ a square number. For $6$ and $8$ you presumably meant $36$ and $64$?

Comment: @Stinking Bishop you are right. It was an error on my part which has been corrected.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe unfortunately I can't choose 0. The square has to be out of the ones given, the squares of first 9 natural numbers. I did study Pythagorean Triplets but couldn't build anything on it.

Comment: @Rosa the problem is worded ambiguously. You say that a square can be selected any number of times from 0 to $m$. So, that is what I suggested. I chose four squares, and I chose the first one $4$ times, and every other square I chose $0$ times. The problem does not state that the number of times the values are chosen must add up to $m$, although that works as well, $1+1+1+1=2^2$.

Comment: I have not done all the work yet, but my instinct is that, for larger $m$ (say, $m\gt 6$), you will be able to do with just $1$s and $4$s (if $m\equiv 0$ or $m\equiv 1\pmod 3$ and that, if $m\equiv 2\pmod 3$ you will most likely need a single $9$. In addition, the square you are looking for is going to be close to $m$ for large $m$ - may be $\lceil\sqrt{m}\rceil^2$ - i.e. the immediately following square, or one of the two squares following that one.

Comment: @StinkingBishop could you provide a definite proof of such?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is from an ongoing competition:  https://www.codechef.com/NOV19A/problems/LSTBTF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When m=2 you select 9 and 16. Otherwise You start answering this question by asking “what happens if I just select ones?” The sum you get is m. If m is a square, you just select ones and you’re done. Next you want to ask, “can I get to the next square converting ones to fours?” Each time you convert a one to a four, you raise the sum by three, and you normally have enough ones to get past the next square, and you so if the next square is a multiple of three away from m, then you convert ones to fours till you get the next square for your sum and you select those ones and four. If you’re next square isn’t a multiple of three away from n, you have to start considering nines. Converting a one to a nine increases your total by 8, since 8 doesn’t divide 3, you can use this to get your total to something that is a multiple of three less than the next square after it, and you can convert ones to fours to close the remaining gap. For m>64, the gaps between squares are quite large so there is enough room that nines can be used for either the next square or the one after it, so this method works optimally. For smaller m, it provides a decent bound which cuts down on the brute force work.

Comment: I somewhat understand your suggestion, but could you edit your answer to illustrate it with example for better understanding?

Comment: Understood your answer. However, it would not yield the smallest possible selection. For example, in a selection where we choose 5 4s by this method, the smaller alternative would be to choose 4 1s and 1 16.

Comment: I guess it is unclear to me what you’re trying to minimize, I thought you just wanted to find the smallest square that can be written as a sum of m squares, and a way to do it. In that case 16 with four 1s wouldn’t be any better than five 4s.

Answer (score 0):

Brute force actually seems like a reasonable approach for this problem. Here are solutions up to $m=7$.

$$m=1:$$

Since you only need 1 square, any square will do, so choose 1 to keep it minimal.

$$m=2:$$

You are looking for Pythagorean Triples. The smallest is well-known to be $3^2+4^2=5^2$

$$m=3:$$

Try: 
$$\begin{align*}1+1+1 & = 3 \\ 1+1+4 & = 6 \\ 1+4+4 & =9=3^2\end{align*}$$ 
and in three tries, you find a solution.

$$m=4:$$

Try $1+1+1+1=4=2^2$ and in one try, you find a solution.

$$m=5:$$

Try $$\begin{align*}1+1+1+1+1 & = 5 \\ 1+1+1+1+4 & = 8 \\ 1+1+1+4+4 & = 11 \\ 1+1+4+4+4 & = 14 \\ 1+4+4+4+4 & = 17 \\ 4+4+4+4+4 & = 20 \\ 1+1+1+1+9 & = 13 \\ 1+1+1+4+9 & =16 = 4^2\end{align*}$$

That's only 8 tries.

$$m=6:$$

Try $$\begin{align*}1+1+1+1+1+1 & = 6 \\ 1+1+1+1+1+4 & = 9 = 3^2\end{align*}$$

Two tries.

$$m=7:$$

Try $$\begin{align*}1+1+1+1+1+1+1 & = 7 \\ 1+1+1+1+1+1+4 & = 10 \\ 1+1+1+1+1+4+4 & = 13 \\ 1+1+1+1+4+4+4 & = 16 = 4^2\end{align*}$$

4 tries.

Honestly, brute force seems like a pretty reasonable approach. You can find solutions relatively quickly every time.

Comment: my sole concern with brute force lies in the fact that m can be as big as 10^6. Would a selections of just 1 and 4 be sufficient then?

Comment: 1, 4, and 9. In general, for any $m>7$, there exists $n$ such that $(n-1)^2<m\le n^2$. And if $n^2-m\equiv 0 \pmod{3}$, then you just needs 1s and 4s. If $n^2-m\equiv 1\pmod{3}$, then you need 2x 9's and all the rest would be 1s and 4s. If $n^2-m \equiv 2\pmod{3}$, then you need one 9 and all the rest would be 1s and 4s. I'm not sure about ever needing 2x 9s.

Comment: Seems viable and logical. I'll run some tests of my own to confirm. However, what do you mean by not needing 2x9s when you say before it that 2x9s will be needed in a particular case?

Comment: I am not sure if they are needed. It may be that case will never arise. Robo300 seems to think it will never arise.

Comment: Okay. I'll test out both scenarios. Thanks :)

Comment: The suggestions you made are right. However, the issue here is that the selection is not the smallest possible selection, as I explained to Robo300. Otherwise this was the perfect solution :(

Comment: You need to be more specific with what you mean by "smallest". Because the example you gave Robo300 includes a 16, which is larger than any number selected with the process Robo300 and I suggested. However, if "smallest" means sum of the squares, then you need to update your original problem to make that distinction apparent. Currently, it reads that the individual squares should be minimal, not their sum.